# How to set already running binary to run at startup

Tags: macos, go, launchd, launchctl

I have a Go program that is supposed to run as a daemon with minimal front-end for the user (just an icon in the system tray.)

The fact that it's written in Go doesn't really matter much, the main issue I have is getting a binary (that is already running) to run at startup on a Mac.

I can set the binary to run at startup like so:

```
cp daemon.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/daemon.plist
```

(`cp` the plist into the LaunchAgents directory)

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/daemon.plist
```

(then load the plist with `launchctl`.)

And that works fine.  The only issue is that `launchctl load` **it starts another instance of the binary that is already running**.  I want to be able to enable (and disable) running the binary at startup for the binary that is running, without starting another instance of it.

And here's the `.plist` file if you want to see it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>daemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Daemon.app/Contents/MacOS/daemon</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Change `<key>RunAtLoad</key><true/>` to `<key>RunAtLoad</key><false/>` and start then call `launchctl load ....`  and `launchctl start daemon`

Comment: @George Oikonomou That doesn't work.  The binary is already running.  I don't want to start it manually with launchctl.  All I want to do is dynamically enable/disable running a program at startup without restarting the program or creating another instance of it.

Comment: launchctl should start a new instance if the main process of your software is still around. Are you using any kind of subprocess or forks (daemonize)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

So first, the binary is running.  It starts out as not enabled to run at startup.  To initialize, you `cp` the `plist` to the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` directory:

```
cp daemon.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/daemon.plist
```

And the `plist` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>daemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Daemon.app/Contents/MacOS/daemon</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**NOTE: The `RunAtLoad` key is set to `false`.**

Then we load it into `launchctl`:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/daemon.plist
```

It shouldn't load since `RunAtLoad` is set to `false`.

Then, we can enable and disable running at startup like so:

To enable:

- Set `RunAtLoad` to `true`
- `cp` the `plist` over

To disable:

- Set `RunAtLoad` to `false`
- `cp` the `plist` over

Kind of hacky, but it works.